# Variable unexpectedly changing value in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm doing some code that I'm running on a VM and this code does directly interact with memory addresses, (which might be the issue I'm not entirely sure) I've been finding that my variable has been changing value without me intentionally changing it, which I'm sure is a byproduct of me changing memory directly I'm not sure

I've managed to identify when the variable change occurs but I am still unsure as to what has changed it

```
mov ax, [cmdsize]
add al, 0x30
call printChar <-- variable is fine here
; waits for user input from the keyboard
mov ah, 0
int 0x16
cmp al, 0x0D
je inputend
; prints the entered character and stores it in memory
call printChar
mov di, cx
add di, [terminalcmdmem]
mov [di], al
mov ax, [cmdsize]
add al, 0x30
call printChar <-- it's changed when I print here
```

```
printChar:
    mov ah, 0x0e 
    int 0x10
    ret
```

I've tried commenting out lines of the code such as `mov di,cx` through `mov [di], al` but no results, I guesss it might be the interrupt but I find that rather strange and wouldnt know what to use otherwise

I cannot use a debugger if you are wondering as this is all directly interacting with memory and my computer throws a fit if I do that so I launch this on a VM using qemu (this is all loaded onto a floppy image and loaded through that)

Edit:

Forgot to mention `inputend` is not called until some time after the issue occurs

Comment: You can debug the program running in qemu

Comment: @harold apologies this is part of a terminal that I am running on a custom bootloader, kernel, os, etc, if there is still a way to do this that would be very helpful to my code

Comment: I haven't tried that, but AFAIK using the [remote debugging](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/gdb.html) facilities of QEMU should work regardless

Comment: @harold thank you very much, ill try this and if i get results i will post them!

Comment: @harold I'm having trouble adding break points and stepping through my code as I am custom building the image that is being loaded into qemu, is there any way you suggest I could find a way around this?

Comment: What trouble? It doesn't really matter how you build the image. As for the actual problem, do you have stack set up properly? Is the whole code available for testing?

Comment: is there like a website i could share the entire code on? like a snippet thing?

Comment: @Jester the trouble is it says no symbol table loaded

Comment: Yeah well you don't need symbol table even though that may be helpful. You can always just use disassembly and raw addresses. Depending on how you build you can also load a symbol file separately. Any pastebin site should work if your code is small enough or you can use google drive or github.

Comment: @Jester [sorry some code isn't commented and is rather sketchy at some points](https://gist.github.com/sopho-s/ceb89023e04bec4da6e3c52b123a0003)

Comment: Yeah as I expected, you do not set `ss`. Also you set `sp` to `0x8000` and stack grows down so it will collide with your data assuming `ss` is zero initially.

Comment: @Jester apologise i sorta realised recently that i am knees deep in stuff I'm still quite unfamiliar with, but I'm sticking with it, do you mind telling me what i need to do with ss reg?

Comment: Make sure `ss:sp` points to somewhere that does not collide with your other memory usage. Do not assume `ss` is set in any particular way by the BIOS. For example, you can do `xor ax, ax; mov ss, ax; mov sp, 0x9000`

Comment: @Jester thank you very much for that, do you want to submit it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @Jester But i still am having issues with the debugger though